# Late Initialization Error: Field 'animation' has not been initialized. in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Wmg.png)

this is the error i was getting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHEzJ.png)

and this is my code, basically i was doing a simple ripple animation program.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB34m.png)

please help me to get out from this

Comment: Where it says `enter image description here` you are supposed to enter an image description...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is **build method** try to use the variable `animation` before initialised.

try to add bool flag

```
bool isLoading=true;

 @override
 void initState() {

   isLoading = true;
   super.initState();
   // do all the inits
   isLoading = false;
 }
```

then inside the build method check weather it init or not and build the widget based on it.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return isLoading?Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()):/*YOUR ACTUAL WIDGET*/
}
```